# Next.js - different fetching type methods

Tags: next.js

So, i'm new to next.js, and it's been kinda hard to understand the different fetching methods that you have.

**My Question**: So, we have, getServerSidePros, getStaticProps, getStaticPath and a hook in next.js called swr, now, trying to read the docs and watching different tutorials, i kinda understood the three first methods to fetch data, but, when i saw swr, i just got confused

**My Goal** : So this is simple, can you explain me shortly what those methods mean ? specially the swr, because swr it's like a combination of getServerSideProps and getStaticProps, but, if swr do that, why do we use getServerSideProps and the other one ?

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Even though [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) was developed by Vercel, it is not part of Next.js - it's a standalone React Hooks (client-side) library for data fetching.

Comment: I'd recommend you a read through the [Pre-rendering and Server-side rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering) docs.